# Adding and Removing Panels GWT Dynamically

Tags: java, gwt

I'm trying to add/remove panels in GWT. First I declare panels and some Labels (which act as buttons).

```
    DockPanel dockPanel = new DockPanel();
    RootLayoutPanel rootLayout = RootLayoutPanel.get();

    Label one = new Label("First Button");
    Label two = new Label("Second Button");
```

Then I have this which initialises various panels

```
    public void initPanels() {

        dockPanel.add(one, DockPanel.EAST);
        rootLayout.add(dockPanel);
```

I add some click handlers which then sends requests to this class, which would then remove a panel and replace it with another, only I can't work out how to do it:

```
public void getActivePanel(String activePanelName){

    if (activePanelName==null){ 
        dockPanel.add(one, DockPanel.EAST);
    }

    else if (activePanelName == "two"){

                    //can't figure this bit out
        //dockPanel.remove(AnotherLabel);
        //dockPanel.remove((IsWidget) DockPanel.EAST);
        //dockPanel.add(two, DockPanel.EAST);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
dockPanel.remove(one);
dockPanel.add(two, DockPanel.EAST);
```

Comment: Hmm yeah, thought that'd be a solution but the page doesn't update - nothing is removed/added

Comment: Must be me - tried it on a simpler problem and it worked - ill accept the answer in 3 mins